# How do I export a JSON file to a URL in ExpressJS and then also be able to import the JSON file from that URL?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to pass information between two applications running on different servers, so I need to export a JSON file to a URL, which another server can take that URL and import the JSON file. I am using ExpressJS. I have no idea how to go about this. Thank you for you help!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could be a solution, to write a little handler at the import server.

Something like this:

```
express().use('/api/import-json', (req, res, next) => {

// save the req.body.data file at req.body.path

})
```

And then set a HTMLPostRequest from the Export api with an Object structured something like that:

```
reqData = {
  path: '/the/path/where/you/want/to/save/your/json',
  dat: {...jsonData}
}
```

But beware without Security improvement everyone can write data on your Server an this could lead to some big issues